# Change a value of a variable within an array variable value in php

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, while-loop

I am trying to update a variable value that is within an array variable value.

You will see I am writing out a file with: `file_put_contents()`. The `implode("\r\n", $contents)...` contains the `$contents` variable.

I need `$body_file_count` to increment every iteration of the `if ($i == $per_file) {...`

It's pretty evident the $contents array cannot update a variable value in this case `$body_file_count`.

`$body_file_count` is the number of files outputted. It's actually the same number in the file title: `$file_count`...

Basically, I just need to write the `$body_file_count` to the:

```
$default_contents=$contents=array("BODY CONTENT TOP . "$body_file_count" . ");
```

on each if `($i == $per_file) {` iteration. Obviously I could scrap `$body_file_count` if I could pass $file_count to the `$content` as `$file_count` is updating the title as expected.

```
$body_file_count = 0;
$footer = "FOOTER";
$default_contents = $contents = array("BODY CONTENT TOP . "$body_file_count" . ");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $line = "...";
    $contents[] = $line; // Each array element will be a line in the text file
    $i++;
    $recs++;
    if ($i == $per_file) {
        $contents[] = $footer; // Add the footer to the end
        file_put_contents($_POST["a"] . "-#" . $file_count .  "-" . date('Y') . "-" . $_POST["b"] . "-" . $recs . "-" . $txtdate .  '.txt', implode("\r\n", $contents));
        $i = 0;
        $recs = 0;
        $contents = $default_contents;
        $file_count++;
        $body_file_count++;
    } // End of if()
} // End of while()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First beware that you have forget to add the string concatenation operator (".") on the $default_contents initialitation

I don't know if i have understand well your question. If i have understand well your problem you can try to update the the $default_contents everytime that you change $body_file_count++

---

```
$body_file_count = 0;
$footer = "FOOTER";
$default_contents = $contents = array("BODY CONTENT TOP . " . $body_file_count . " . ");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $line = "...";
    $contents[] = $line; // Each array element will be a line in the text file
    $i++;
    $recs++;
    if ($i == $per_file) {
        $contents[] = $footer; // Add the footer to the end
        file_put_contents($_POST["a"] . "-#" . $file_count .  "-" . date('Y') . "-" . $_POST["b"] . "-" . $recs . "-" . $txtdate .  '.txt', implode("\r\n", $contents));
        $i = 0;
        $recs = 0;
        $file_count++;
        $body_file_count++;
        $default_contents = array("BODY CONTENT TOP . " . $body_file_count . " . ");
        $contents = $default_contents;
    } // End of if()
} // End of while()
```

---

Also if you don't need for anything else this variable besides to provide an initial content then you can just take it away

---

```
$body_file_count = 0;
$footer = "FOOTER";
$contents = array("BODY CONTENT TOP . " . $body_file_count . " . ");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $line = "...";
    $contents[] = $line; // Each array element will be a line in the text file
    $i++;
    $recs++;
    if ($i == $per_file) {
        $contents[] = $footer; // Add the footer to the end
        file_put_contents($_POST["a"] . "-#" . $file_count .  "-" . date('Y') . "-" . $_POST["b"] . "-" . $recs . "-" . $txtdate .  '.txt', implode("\r\n", $contents));
        $i = 0;
        $recs = 0;
        $file_count++;
        $body_file_count++;
        $contents = array("BODY CONTENT TOP . " . $body_file_count . " . ");
    } // End of if()
} // End of while()
```

---

Comment: I thought I tried this already, but I did not place the $contents at the end of the if iteration. It appears to be outputting the $file_count OK now. Thank you for the suggestion.